# How to enforce form input constraints are satisfied before calling function?

Tags: jquery, forms

I use an onclick event to call a function that submits formData content to a database.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "input.my_class", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
myFunction();  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="submit" class="my_class">
```

The input fields in the form have various constrains ie:

- `required`
- `type="number"`
- `step="any"`

**Question**

These constraints are not enforced when clicking on the submit button.

What logic do I need to introduce conditions to the effect of:

"Only call the function `myFunction` if form input constraints have been met"

**Edit:** I should clarify I was trying to implement a 'no frills' (ie no plugin) solution that complimented the browsers actions in alerting the user to field constraints.  If this is not best practise though I will look for a validation plugin from somewhere like http://www.unheap.com/section/validation/.

Comment: You can reinvent the wheel, or use an existing library: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 2):

I suppose do the checking before you call `myFunction`

```
$(document).on("click", "input.my_class", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //CHECK HERE, IF BAD, return;
    //if (this.value && this.value.length > someLength) //so on
    myFunction();  
});
```